# How can I iterate N given times a function in prolog?

Tags: prolog

Iam trying to create a function that iterates N given times another function I have over a list, but I don´t know why for numbers above 0the answer is no.
The function cells aplies a set of rules to each element of a list a turns it into an 'x' or an 'o'
but qhen using the function evol to make N iterations it doesn´t work.

```
color(o).
color(x).

% Rule definition
rule(o,o,o,_,o). % Null rule
rule(x,o,o,r(A,_,_,_,_,_,_),A) :- color(A).
rule(o,x,o,r(_,B,_,_,_,_,_),B) :- color(B).
rule(o,o,x,r(_,_,C,_,_,_,_),C) :- color(C).
rule(x,o,x,r(_,_,_,D,_,_,_),D) :- color(D).
rule(x,x,o,r(_,_,_,_,E,_,_),E) :- color(E).
rule(o,x,x,r(_,_,_,_,_,F,_),F) :- color(F).
rule(x,x,x,r(_,_,_,_,_,_,G),G) :- color(G).

cells(State, Rules, Cells) :- 
    triplets(State,_, Rules, Sols),
    my_append(Sols,[o],Result),
    Cells = Result.

% Creates a list of lists of triplets form a list given aplies
% the rules to the triplets and saves the result in the list Sols

triplets(State, _,Rules, [o|Sols]) :-
    triplets_helper([o|State], Triplets,Rules, Sols).

triplets_helper([X1,X2], [[X1,X2,o]],Rules, [Sol]) :- 
    apply_rule(X1,X2,o,Rules,Sol),
    !.                                                  % insert null at the end
triplets_helper([X1,X2,X3|Xs], [[X1,X2,X3]|Ys],Rules, [Sol|Sols]) :-
    apply_rule(X1,X2,X3,Rules,Sol),
    triplets_helper([X2,X3|Xs], Ys,Rules, Sols).

% Applies the rules to each triplet    
apply_rule(X,Y,Z,Rules,Re) :- 
 rule(X,Y,Z,Rules,Re).

% Unites lists
my_append([], A, A).
my_append([H|T], A2, [H|A3]) :- my_append(T, A2, A3). 

% Function evol

evol(0, r(_,_,_,_,_,_,_), Cells):-
    Cells = [o,x,o].
evol(N, Rules, Cells) :-
    evol_auxiliar(N, [o,x,o], Rules, Cells),
    evol(N, Rules, _Cells1).
    

%Recursive evol

evol_auxiliar(0, Cells, _, Cells).
evol_auxiliar(N, Input, Rules, Result):-
    cells(Input, Rules, Cells),
    N = N - 1,
    evol_auxiliar(N, Cells, Rules, Result).
```

Comment: `N = N - 1` should be `N is N - 1`, for arithmetic.

Comment: More precisely, use a different variable, e.g. `N1 is N - 1`, and then use `N1` below. Careful, with this fix there seem to be an infinite recursion but I am not sure exactly what is the main predicate to call. Maybe you could add a little bit more precision about how you test that.

Comment: "it doesn´t work." you need to do a bit better than this. What exactly do you expect to happen and how is it different from what you get? Have you debugged your code to see what is really happening?

Comment: Provide a sample query. How do I call `cells` predicate?
(By the way, functions are not a thing in prolog. You mean "predicate".)